# Menú de anclas haciendo scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, scss

Hola tengo un menú de anclas actualmente que se mueve a través del sitio web de forma suave, mi problema es el siguiente.

INICIO | PERFIL | DATOS | CONTACTO

Quiero que conforme baje haciendo scroll se vaya seleccionando la zona a la que pertenece en el menu de anclas por ejemplo si con el scroll bajo a la zona DATOS me gustaría que datos estuviese en negrita, si sigo bajando a contacto pues que el negrita pase a contacto

```
<ul class="navegacion">
  <li data-sly-repeat="${nav.elements}" class="menu-anclali">
    <a href="#${item.id}" class="cuerpo">${item.id}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const title_1 = document.getElementById("title_1");
const title_2 = document.getElementById("title_2");

const content_1 = document.getElementById("content_1");
const content_2 = document.getElementById("content_2");

window.onscroll = () => {
  const scrollY = window.scrollY;
  if (scrollY >= content_1.offsetTop) {
    title_1.className = "active"
    title_2.className = ""
} else {
    title_1.className = ""
  }
  if (scrollY >= content_2.offsetTop) {
    title_2.className = "active"
    title_1.className = ""
 } else {
    title_2.className = ""
  }
}
```

```css
body  {
  margin: 100px 0 600px;
}

.title-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <span id="title_1">Titulo 1</span> | <span id="title_2">Titulo 2</span>
</div>

<p id="content_1">Contenido titulo 1</p>
<p id="content_2">Contenido titulo 2</p>
```

Comment: El código muy bien, pero para que una [respuesta sea correcta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) debe tener una explicación para que si otra persona no la entiende le pueda ayudar. Te invito a editar tu pregunta y añadir comentarios y explicaciones.